# Raspberry Pi: Using framebuffer image viewer (FBI), is there a way to change an image without opening another FBI display?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So, I have a TFT Screen and a Raspberry Pi that is hooked up to 4 buttons. When a button is pressed, the image that is associated with that button will display on the screen using fbi. With the way I have it written, when a button is pressed, it will create a new fbi display on top of the old one. So, I end up have a bunch of fbi displays just stacked on top of each other.

Is there a way to just replace the current fbi display with a new one instead of creating one to stack on top of the old one?

Here's my python code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


os.system("sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a normal.png")

var = 1  
while var == 1:
  if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
    os.system("sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a happy.png")

  if (GPIO.input(22) == False):
    os.system("sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a sad.png")

  if (GPIO.input(27) == False):
    os.system("sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a angry.png")

  if (GPIO.input(18) == False):
    os.system("sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a surprised.png")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could kill the process before displaying the new image.

```
....
 if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
    os.system("sudo killall -9 fbi")
    os.system("sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a happy.png")

....
```

Comment: I am working with FIM (FBI improved) and the -9 option helped me get rid of a flickering problem I had between 2 consecutive calls.